# How can I write a for loop so that it tests all 5 of my test cases?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, user-defined-functions, finance

I am supposed to work out the periodic investment amount given the target wealth.

This is my user defined code:

```
def contribution_calculator(target_wealth, rate, duration, periodicity):
    inv_amt = -npf.pmt(rate/100/periodicity, duration*periodicity, 0, target_wealth)
    return inv_amt
```

These are my 5 test cases which I have put them into their respective list.

```
target_wealth = [1000000, 1000000, 3000000, 3000000, 2000000]

rate = [2.5, 2.5, 0.5, 4.0, 3.0]

duration = [25, 12, 25, 25, 10]

periodicity = [12, 1, 12, 12, 2]
```

For example, the values for test case 1 are 1000000, 2.5, 25, 12.

How can I write a for loop such that it will test all the 5 given test cases?

Comment: Do you also want to test the combination, for example: 2000000, 2.5, 25, 12 ?

Comment: @balandongiv yes please! I would like to test my other combinations, such as 1000000, 2.5, 12, 1 for test case 2, and 3000000, 0.5, 25, 12 for test case 3. Is there a way I could do a for loop to test all these cases using my user defined function contribution_calculator?

Comment: Ah, if you want to test all combinations, you need `itertools.product` rather than `zip`

Comment: @sabik i see! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `zip()` and tuple unpacking, like this:

```
for tw, r, d, p in zip(target_wealth, rate, duration, periodicity):
    ...
```

Perhaps rename the lists, so you can use the full variable names:

```
for target_wealth, rate, duration, periodicity in zip(target_wealths, rates, durations, periodicities):
    ...
```

PS: If you want to test all combinations, rather than corresponding values, you can use `itertools.product` instead of `zip`:

```
import itertools
for target_wealth, rate, duration, periodicity in itertools.product(target_wealths, rates, durations, periodicities):
    ...
```

Comment: Doing bother unpacking: `for x in zip(...): contribution_calculator(*x)`